# How to change random text with interval 5 seconds in Vue (Nuxt js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm a beginner in Vue and I have some problem to change random text with interval 5 second when the page is loading.

```js
<template>
  <section class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        Welcome {{ whois }}
      </h1>
 </section>
<template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      whois: ['Student', 'Developer', 'Programmer']
    }
  },
  // methods: {
  //   randomWhois(){
      
  //   }
  // },
  // beforeMount() {
  //   this.randomWhois();
  // }
}
</script>
```

I hope when the interval 5 seconds, my text is always changed.

Example: (always change in 5 seconds)

---

**Welcome Student**

**Welcome Developer**

**Welcome Programmer**

---

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `mounted`, set up an interval to fire your method every 5 seconds.
This method will just shift your `whois` array to the left.
And then in your template, change the `Welcome` to display the first element in the array `{{ whois[0] }}`.

```
<template>
  <section class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        Welcome {{ whois[0] }}
      </h1>
    </section>
<template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      whois: ['Student', 'Developer', 'Programmer']
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    window.setInterval(()=>{
      this.pollPerson();
    }, 5000);

  },
  methods: {
    pollPerson(){
      const first = this.whois.shift();
      this.whois = this.whois.concat(first);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```